# Selenium web scraping. ec2 instance can't locate element even though it works on my local machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to **scrape** data from webpage.
Below code works on my local window machine but it doesn't work on ec2 linux instance.

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  

option = webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
option.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=dir_firefox_driver, options=option)
driver.get("https://www.mwave.me/en/mcountdown")
time.sleep(3)
driver.set_window_size(600, 800)
temp = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".chart_view_more button")
```

I saw the article that wait until element appear, so I tried below code

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=dir_firefox_driver, options=option)
driver.get("https://www.mwave.me/en/mcountdown")
time.sleep(3)
driver.set_window_size(600, 800)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".chart_view_more button"))
    )
except:
    print("there is no element")
    quit()
temp = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".chart_view_more button")
```

It also doesn't work. I can't find difference in my local machine and ec2 instance.
Can somebody give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few things you can try to solve this issue:-

Instead of

```
driver.set_window_size(600, 800)
```

use :

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

also use the below code :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=dir_firefox_driver, options=option)
driver.get("https://www.mwave.me/en/mcountdown")
time.sleep(3)
driver.maximize_window()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".chart_view_more button"))
    )
except:
    print("there is no element")
    quit()
temp = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".chart_view_more button")
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But why I set the window size 600 by 800 is the button is active when it under the size(or smaller).

Comment: do this instead `driver.maximize_window()`